# Icon is not displayed on the chat window of QnA Bot

Tags: azure, botframework

I have tested the Microsoft QnA Bot with a positive restult. Everything works fine as expected. I can see next to a message the name of the sending entity. Next to the message I was expecting to see an image, however in my case I do not see it.

1. I have uploaded an icon on my service on  https://qnamaker.ai/
2. I have also uploaded one on the https://dev.botframework.com/
   Uploading the icons I was aware of the size 50px x 50px.
3. On the test on dev.botframework.com/ the icon was also not displayed.

I havent found any other suitable answer online.
Does anyone have a recommendation?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing the bot icon is because the webchat module on the Bot Portal at https://dev.botframework.com does not support bot icon images.

Some channels do support it such as Skype or Slack. Try testing your bot on Skype, you will see the bot icon image there.

Comment: Fair enough! Good to know! Thanks!